# What are the strengths and weaknesses of using a single 'burner' computer vs. many public access computers over a sustained period?

Tags: privacy, hardware, anonymity

Assuming that the user is accessing/publishing related sensitive information over this period, and also assuming that they would take additional precautions in both scenarios, such as a Tails live USB, and an on-screen keyboard to prevent keylogging where it may be a risk.

The main aim is to remain anonymous.

Thank you!

Comment: On-screen keyboards don't prevent all keyloggers from functioning

Comment: Ha, yeah, I know, it's just an example to aid the question. What I was really trying to put across is that I wouldn't be using the computers in their 'native', most vulnerable states.

Answer (score 2):

> Quick answer

- Buy and configure a disposable computer.
- Limit device usage to a single purpose.
- Follow information hygiene practices.

> Disposable vs public access computers

Firstly, the reconstruction of your data and conduct by third parties depends on whether your conduct was localised or networked.

The reconstruction of network communication involves tracing a thread through various servers with search warrants until your identity and conduct is known. The reconstruction of localised behaviour requires either physical access to the computer or knowing your location whilst you are using it in order to eavesdrop in a variety of ways.

So:

- A disposable computer is only *marginally better* than public computers for internet activity, as most of web anonymity depends on following strict rules of compartmentalisation and online hygiene.
- A disposable computer is *generally better* than public computers for non-HTTP network communication as public computers usually lack appropriate tools like `ssh`, `tor`, `freenet` and `pgp`.
- A disposable computer is *quite superior* for all localised activities as you control your data and can destroy it when required.

You pay for this improved anonymity by having to buy and configure the single-purpose disposable computer.

Public computing can cost nothing and requires minimal technical expertise to use within the limits of its anonymity. However availability of public computing is wildly variable, both in time of day and location - which limits how random your access behaviour will really be.

> Regarding disposable devices

Let us consider a disposable computer as any computer that you are willing and able to physically destroy to protect sensitive information or conduct.

A distinction should be made between self-contained disposable computers and live-boot distributions requiring a host computer to execute instructions. There are also new *pc-on-a-stick* hybrids that combine the portability of USB with the security of isolated CPU and storage.

**Mobile phones** are either a dreadful or an excellent option for anonymity - depending on what type of operating system and software is installed. Typically mobile phones are dreadful as they haemorrhage information out of every conceivable transceiver; know your location and conduct intimately; explicitly aggregate your identity for various commercial reasons; and have the interface security of a wet paper bag. However, a hardened custom OS with the transceivers tightly controlled or entirely disabled can make for an excellent option under ordinary use cases.

**Laptops and netbooks** are less portable and typically more expensive disposable solution than a mobile phone but require far less technical expertise to establish as anonymity-orientated machine.

**Live-boot USB sticks** will rely on the security of the host computer and hence the level of trust in that computer. They are the cheapest and most mature of the portable anonymity solutions, but you will find many public access computers disable booting from USB or prohibit such conduct in any case - as the flow of access is both ways. You could in effect manipulate the (unencrypted) host computer.

**PC-on-a-stick** solutions are a less mature technology than live-boot disk-images but, depending on their operating system and feature set, are probably the best overall solution for anonymity as they work with any accessible HDMI monitor and almost completely isolated from the surrounding environment.